# MOXy DynamicEntity with JSON?

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, moxy

I'm trying to use DynamicEntity to unmarshal some simple JSON, and it's totally bombing on me. Docs are rather sparse, is it even possible to do this? I'm basically doing this;

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DynamicEntity.class);
DynamicEntity entity = (DynamicEntity) jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(entityStream);
```

This is straight from the XML docs here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/Dynamic/XmlToDynamicEntity

And I get;
Caused by:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
org.eclipse.persistence.dynamic.DynamicEntity is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.eclipse.persistence.dynamic.DynamicEntity
```

Has anyone managed to get this to work? I'm basically trying to avoid building POJOs since my backend store doesnt care about them anyway, I just want to deserialize to a generic object and pass it along. In .NET I'd just use `dynamic` but I'm pretty stumped on how to do this with Moxy.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get `DynamicEntity`, it is neccessary to use `DynamicJAXBContext`. It can be configured using the following in *jaxb.properties* file:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.DynamicJAXBContextFactory
```

or you can use `DynamicJAXBContextFactory` directly.

Although Dynamic MOXY does not require any java classes for the bindings (the POJOs), you need to provide binding metadata when creating the context. It can be XSD or binding.xml that describes the mapping. So instead of creating the context using `JAXBContext.newInstance(DynamicEntity.class)`, you would need to use alternative methods - see links below.

See example here (using XSD):
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/Dynamic/JAXBContextFromXMLSchema

or more complex example using binding.xml and also JSON:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/Dynamic/Flickr